# I keep getting an internal server error every time I make a axios.put requets in my API in React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleUpdate(user, token, e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    axios.put(`https://itshorrortime.herokuapp.com/users/${user}`, {

      Username: this.state.Username,
      Password: this.state.Password,
      Email: this.state.Email,
      Birthday: this.state.Birthday
    },
      {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        localStorage.setItem("user", data.Username);
        console.log(response.data);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.toJSON());
        console.log(e.response.data);
      })

  }
```

This is my JS code. The function is called in a form:

```
 <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleUpdate(user, token, e)}>
          <Form.Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Form.Label>Username:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='text'
              required
              minLength="6"
              maxLength="12"
              placeholder='Enter Username'

            />
          </Form.Row>

          <Form.Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Form.Label>Password:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='text'
              required
              minLength="6"
              maxLength="12"
              placeholder='Enter Password'


            />
          </Form.Row>
          <Form.Row className="justify-content-center">

            <Form.Label>Email:</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='text'
              required
              placeholder='Enter Email'

            />

          </Form.Row>
          <Form.Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Form.Label >Birthday: </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='date'
              required

            />
          </Form.Row>


          <Button type="submit" variant="dark" block >Submit</Button>
        </Form >
```

and here is the code in my API

```
app.put('/users/:Username', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
  let hashedPassword = Users.hashPassword(req.body.Password);
  Users.findOneAndUpdate({ Username: req.params.Username }, {
    $set:
    {
      Username: req.body.Username,
      Password: hashedPassword,
      Email: req.body.Email,
      Birthday: req.body.Birthday
    }
  }, { new: true })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) return
      res.status(400).send(req.params.Username + ' was not found');
    }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send(`Error: ${err.stack}`)
    })
})
```

Can anyone point me in the direct of where I should troubleshoot? I have been working on this for 16+ hours and still am getting a 500 error. I have an axios.post, axios.get, axios.delete method that all works fine. I can make those requests - so I know it's not a problem with the token or authentication. I formatted the form just like my login form and my login form works perfectly - this is a really strange error and I would appreciate any help I could get :)

Comment: more details needed about your internal 500 server error. what is telling you?

Comment: can you provide more information about the error you can check it from Heroku in the logs section or by running the server locally

Comment: do you use express or koa and mongodb for your application?

Comment: what is the value of { user }? you are passing to the axios.put method please consider  logging it to the console to see whether or not it is undefined

Comment: I am using express for the application. This is the exact error:     
   index.072cb075.js:28092 PUT https://itshorrortime.herokuapp.com/users/testing 500 (Internal Server Error)                                                                                 
{message: "Request failed with status code 500", name: "Error", description: undefined, number: undefined, fileName: undefined, …}

Comment: I did try logging it into the console - it is defined and it is stored in local storage as well.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions on how to troubleshoot this one:

- Put some logging in the catch block of the put handler in your API to see if that's maybe where the 500 is originating
- If so, try removing the aggregation pipeline (don't do $set: in the update parameter you pass to findOneAndUpdate - per Mongoose doc, [just pass the object as the update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)) to see if that's causing the problem
- You should also look at the .then in your put handler. It looks like you do a return before sending the response. Check to see if the user is populated in there - again that could be related to the $set if not